# Replace/Redraw a TextBox 3D border using a custom color

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, user-controls, gdi+

> SCENARIO

In **WinForms**, I've sub-classed a **Textbox** to draw my own border with a solid color when `BorderStyle` property is set to `Flat`, `None`, or `Fixed3D`.

> PROBLEM

When I try to draw a border with a color when my **TextBox** property is set `Fixed3D`, the border is not properly drawn on the surface:

[image]

What you see in the image is a zoomed TextBox with:

BackColor = Black

BorderStyle = Fixed3D (the white thing)

And the red thing is my intent of border.

> QUESTION

In C# or VB.Net, how I can replace/redraw the 3D border to do what I want?, I mean replace/hide/redraw the white border of the image above.

> CODE

This is what I've tried on the `OnPaint` method:

```
    Using g As Graphics = Graphics.FromHwnd(Me.Handle)

        ' Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle(0, 0, Me.Width, Me.Height)

        ' Dim pen As New Pen(Color.Black, 2)
        ' pen.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset
        ' g.DrawRectangle(pen, rect)

        ControlPaint.DrawBorder(Graphics.FromHwnd(Me.Handle),
                                Me.ClientRectangle,
                                Me.borderColor1,
                                ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)

    End Using
```

Also I've tried to use the `DrawBorder3D` method but any of its overloads accept a color?

Comment: have you looked at the following I think this may help http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773178(VS.85).aspx

Comment: @DJ KRAZE thankyou so much!, but due to my low experience in GDI+ I can't notice if one of those methods could help me with this, anyways I will deep in that to see if one of them can help me.

Comment: that method wont turn out well.  you are drawing inside the text area rather than around the controls.  the borders are actually set when the textbox window is created as part of CreateParams

Comment: ...also I am not sure that you are trying to overcome the TextBox border, but trying to change the way that the user's theme is applied/used.  With no theme, they normal appearance is a bit different: http://imgur.com/1tr5olz